# Select unique nodes based on a combination of two attribute values

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have some XML that looks something like this:

```
<Root>
    <Documents>
        <Document id="1"/>
    </Documents>
    <People>
        <Person id="1"/>
        <Person id="2"/>
    </People>
    <Links>
        <Link personId="1" documentId="1"/>
        <Link personId="1" documentId="1"/>
        <Link personId="2" documentId="1"/>
    </Links>
</Root>
```

And I am interested in getting only the 'Link' elements that have a unique combination of 'personId's and 'documentId's, so these two links:

```
<Root>
    <Links>
        <Link personId="1" documentId="1"/>
        <Link personId="2" documentId="1"/>
    </Links>
</Root>
```

How might I go about doing that? I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227711/how-to-select-unique-nodes-in-xslt), though I feel mine is slightly more complex and may not apply...I presumme I am going to need to use the key() function somewhere...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kDocAndPeoById" match="Document|Person" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:key name="kLinksByIds" match="Link" 
             use="concat(@personId,'++',@documentId)"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Documents|People|
     Link[count(.|key('kLinksByIds',concat(@personId,'++',@documentId))[1])!=1
          or not(key('kDocAndPeoById',@personId)/self::Person)
          or not(key('kDocAndPeoById',@documentId)/self::Document)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Root>
    <Links>
        <Link personId="1" documentId="1"></Link>
        <Link personId="2" documentId="1"></Link>
    </Links>
</Root>
```

If you have no interest into checking if there is such Document or Person @id, then this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kLinksByIds" match="Link" 
              use="concat(@personId,'++',@documentId)"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Documents|People|
  Link[count(.|key('kLinksByIds',concat(@personId,'++',@documentId))[1])!=1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Root>
    <Links>
        <Link personId="1" documentId="1"></Link>
        <Link personId="2" documentId="1"></Link>
    </Links>
</Root>
```

Comment: Good and elegant. (+1). I came up almost with the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine multiple selector attributes into the XPath query, doesn't have to be just a single attribute=value pair.

[Find through multiple attributes in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353843/find-through-multiple-attributes-in-xml)

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the `<Link>`s with something like this, where the `current()` function returns `<Link>`s you're checking for uniqueness.

```
.[not(preceding-sibling::Link[@personId   = current()/@personId and
                              @documentId = current()/@documentId])]
```

The `preceding-sibling::` axis is used to find earlier `<Link>` elements and the part in square brackets checks for matching ID numbers. The `not()` wrapping the whole expression means the entire bracketed expression is true only if NO such preceding sibling matches, i.e. there is no prior `<Link>` with the same person and document IDs.

My XSLT knowledge is rusty so I'll leave that part to you. What I'm thinking is you first find all links with, say, `//Link`, and then filter them in a second step with the above XPath. I tried hard but couldn't think of any way to do it all in one step since this relies on the `current()` function to work.