# How to select the first node for each value of a given attribute using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have a document that looks like this:

```
<template>
 <otherstuff>
 <group name="foo">
 ...stuff...
 </group>
</template>
<template>
 <otherstuff>
 <group name="bar">
 ...different stuff...
 </group>
</template>
<template>
 <otherstuff>
 <group name="foo">
 ...same stuff as first foo group...
 </group>
</template>
```

What I want to do is to call a particular template for each instance of a given group name - so once for "foo" and once for "bar".  Since they're identical, I don't care which of them is used to call this template.

Following the answers to [Select unique nodes based on a combination of two attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566550/select-unique-nodes-based-on-a-combination-of-two-attribute-values), I've produced this code:

```
<xsl:key name="groupsByName" match="//group" use="@name"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//group[count(.|key('groupsByName',@name)[1])!=1]">
        <xsl:call-template name="template-or-group"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The result, however, is that the template isn't called.  I also suspect that since my case is simpler than the question I based my code on, there's probably a simpler way.  My XSLT isn't strong enough to work out what it might be, though.

Comment: The only problem is that you should use `=` instead of `!=` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to replace your template with:

```
<xsl:template match="group[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('groupsByName',@name)[1])]">
  ....
</xsl:template>
```

Or just change your xpath expression to `//group[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('groupsByName',@name)[1])]`.

`count(.|some-node-set)` is usually used to check whether some node belongs to the set or not. Here you need to compare current node with the first some unique node for each group. Also it might be useful to improve an Xpath expression and match only those group elements which have `@name` attributes. Having said all this we get: `//group[@name][generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('groupsByName', @name)[1])]`.

Comment: Changing the expression to `//group[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('groupsByName',@name)[1])]` worked nicely, thank you.  I'm doing some other things within the template, so I didn't want to change the template itself.  Thank you also for the additional explanation.

Comment: Nokolaenkov: This explanation is wrong. Both forms of identity check are used even in classic Jeni Tennison's [page](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Although because the symmetrical inclusion is simplificated, one has to be sure that both expression (`.` and `key($name,$value)[1]`) are singleton and not empty node sets. Symmetrical inclusion from the Set Theory is the pure XPath solution to the identity test, because `generate-id()` is an XSLT only function.

Comment: @Alejandro, why is it wrong? Using generated ids to check whether two nodes are equal or not is more *natural* than than computing power of the set to identify this. Even that `count(.|set-of-one) = 1` is a well-known idiom, it relies on subtle semantics of the `|` operator and `1` is a magic number. If using sets that would be more correct to write `count(.|set-of-one) = count(set-of-one)`. That's matter of taste but that Jenny page says nothing about that. However thanks for raising the question.

Comment: It's wrong because it doesn't explain what I'm explaining, and because a simple replacing of `!=` by `=` would be enough for the question purpose. The symmetrical inclusion isn't a "subtle semantic": A = B <=> A c B ^ B c A

Comment: @Alejandro, sorry cannot agree with your definition of correctness. If you prefer the details then `|` in the xpath it means (spec mode on): "The | operator computes the union of its operands, which must be node-sets." (/spec mode off) In some other languages the very same operator means bitwise OR and therefore definiton of this operator in the XPath is specific (= subtle semantics). Thinking in terms of set theory is of course preferred when dealing with the xpath's `|` but I prefer straightforward `generate-id` way over artifical `count`. YMMV. Maybe I should have noted another opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

**Just replace**:

```
//group[count(.|key('groupsByName',@name)[1])!=1]
```

**with**:

```
//group[count(.|key('groupsByName',@name)[1])=1]
```

**Here is a complete solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="groupsByName" match="//group"
      use="@name"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select=
   "//group[count(.|key('groupsByName',@name)[1])=1]">
   <xsl:call-template name="template-or-group"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="template-or-group">
  <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (fixed to be well-formed):**

```
<t>
    <template>
        <otherstuff/>
        <group name="foo">  ...stuff...  </group>
    </template>
    <template>
        <otherstuff/>
        <group name="bar">  ...different stuff...  </group>
    </template>
    <template>
        <otherstuff/>
        <group name="foo">  ...same stuff as first foo group...  </group>
    </template>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: @Alex-Nikolaenkov: I do not "prefer" this way, but the OP was asking what was the problem with his solution -- the *real* problem was that he was using the `!=` operator instead of the `=` operator. Strictly speaking, I answered the question and you didn't.