# How to find XmlNode parameter value

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XMl Node like below

```
<Parameter Name="TestId" Value="" /><Parameter Name="EntryDate" Value="" /><Parameter Name="formvalue" Value="DBATEST" />
```

Now, i have to to some changes in `formvalue` i.e replace "DBATEST" with "DBAPROD". I tried below code in c#

```
parametersNode.InnerXml.Replace("DBATEST", "DBAPROD");
```

Above code has scope of entire XML and its replacing "DBATEST" with "DBAPROD" outside of `formvalue` whereas i need to do only for `formvalue`. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<Parameters><Parameter Name=\"TestId\" Value=\"\" /><Parameter Name=\"EntryDate\" Value=\"\" /><Parameter Name=\"formvalue\" Value=\"DBATEST\" /></Parameters>");

XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Parameters/Parameter[@Name='formvalue' and @Value='DBATEST']");
node.Attributes["Value"].Value = "DBAPROD";
```

Or alternatively, you could use LINQ to XML to find the exact `Parameter` node you're interested in and change the attribute value like so:

```
var parameters = XElement.Parse("<Parameters><Parameter Name=\"TestId\" Value=\"\" /><Parameter Name=\"EntryDate\" Value=\"\" /><Parameter Name=\"formvalue\" Value=\"DBATEST\" /></Parameters>");
var elements = parameters.Elements("Parameter");
var targetElement = elements.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("Name")?.Value == "formvalue" && e.Attribute("Value")?.Value == "DBATEST");

var targetAttribute = targetElement?.Attribute("Value");
if (targetAttribute != null)
    targetAttribute.Value = "DBAPROD";
```

Comment: How to get exactly the value of `formvalue`. My values can change in later stage of time.

Comment: I've edited the answer to target the `formvalue` node specifically. You should checkout [Find through multiple attributes in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353843/find-through-multiple-attributes-in-xml) for more information

Comment: When i am doing `doc.LoadXml(parametersNode.InnerXml)` i am getting exception like `There are multiple root elements
` How to resolve this?

Comment: The `InnerXml` of the parametersNode will resolve to the three `<Parameter>` elements and that won't be allow because the document is expecting a single node to consider as root. Try `OuterXml` instead.

Comment: Thanks I am able to get value now . Now how to add `XmlNode nodeXML = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Parameters/Parameter[@Name='formValue']");

                nodeXML.Attributes["Value"].Value.Replace('g','G');` Now i need to update my `parametersNode.InnerXml` ..How to do that?

Comment: `Replace` is not a mutating function call, it just creates a new string, so the value it returns needs to be assigned back to something, in this case the `nodeXML.Attributes["Value"].Value`, something like `nodeXML.Attributes["Value"].Value = nodeXML.Attributes["Value"].Value.Replace('g','G')` but prettier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your valid xml is

```
<head>
  <Parameter Name="TestId" Value="" />
  <Parameter Name="EntryDate" Value="" />
  <Parameter Name="formvalue" Value="DBATEST"></Parameter>
</head>
```

Now you can set the attribute value using xml-linq.

```
XDocument exisitngDoc = XDocument.Load(@"address/abc.xml");


 exisitngDoc.Element("head").Elements("Parameter")
    .Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == "formvalue")
.FirstOrDefault().SetAttributeValue("Value", "DBAPROD");
```

Finally you need to save.

```
 exisitngDoc.Save(@"address/abc.xml");
```

Result

```
<hi>
  <Parameter Name="TestId" Value="" />
  <Parameter Name="EntryDate" Value="" />
  <Parameter Name="formvalue" Value="DBAPROD"></Parameter>
</hi>
```